# calculating the ratio of specific record to the total records for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset below and I want to count the `session` column with at least one `action==p` and then calculate the ratio of theses counted `session`s / by total session number (which would be `max(session)` for each `user`.

Added a dummy column `session_with_p` which is T if a `session` for `user` has at least 1 `action==p`. This might help.

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(user, session) %>% 
  mutate(session_with_p = any(action == "p"))
```

```
df<-read.table(text="
user     session   action
1        1          'v'
1        1          'v'      
1        1          'v'
1        2          'd'
1        2          'p'
1        2          'p'
1        3          'p'
2        1          'v'
2        1          'p'
2        2          'v'",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)



resutl_df

user     session   action    session_with_p   ratio_session_posting
1        1          'v'      F                2/3            <-- edit this row added 
1        1          'v'      F                2/3 (0.67)
1        1          'v'      F                2/3
1        2          'd'      T                2/3
1        2          'p'      T                2/3
1        2          'p'      T                2/3
1        3          'p'      T                2/3
2        1          'v'      T                1/2
2        1          'p'      T                1/2
2        2          'v'      F                1/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it by 'weighing' the *session_with_p* column by the number of rows per session such that you can then take a sum per user each session will contribute a 0 or a 1. Dividing by the number of sessions per user and get exactly the ratio that you are looking for:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(user, session) %>% 
  mutate(session_with_p = any(action == "p")/n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(ratio_session_posting = sum(session_with_p)/n_distinct(session)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

We may either get a `summarise`d output after grouping and then do a join with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(user, session) %>% 
   summarise(session_with_p = any(action == "p"),
   .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
   mutate(ratio_session_with_p = sum(session_with_p)/max(session)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   left_join(df, .) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
    user session action session_with_p ratio_session_with_p
   <int>   <int> <chr>  <lgl>                         <dbl>
 1     1       1 v      FALSE                         0.667
 2     1       1 v      FALSE                         0.667
 3     1       1 v      FALSE                         0.667
 4     1       2 d      TRUE                          0.667
 5     1       2 p      TRUE                          0.667
 6     1       2 p      TRUE                          0.667
 7     1       3 p      TRUE                          0.667
 8     2       1 v      TRUE                          0.5  
 9     2       1 p      TRUE                          0.5  
10     2       2 v      FALSE                         0.5
```

---

Or get the count of "p" values per group and use either the `max` or the `first` non-zero value divided by the `max` of 'session' to get the percentage

```
df %>%
   group_by(user, session) %>%
   mutate(Sum_p = sum(action == "p")) %>% 
   group_by(user) %>%
   mutate(ratio_session_posting = max(Sum_p)/max(session)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
    user session action Sum_p ratio_session_posting
   <int>   <int> <chr>  <int>                 <dbl>
 1     1       1 v          0                 0.667
 2     1       1 v          0                 0.667
 3     1       1 v          0                 0.667
 4     1       2 d          2                 0.667
 5     1       2 p          2                 0.667
 6     1       2 p          2                 0.667
 7     1       3 p          1                 0.667
 8     2       1 v          1                 0.5  
 9     2       1 p          1                 0.5  
10     2       2 v          0                 0.5
```

---

Or another option would be to use a summarisation function within the grouping (used `.by` from `devel` version of `dplyr`)

```
df %>%
   mutate(ratio_session_posting = sum(tapply(action == "p", 
    session, FUN = any))/max(session), .by = "user") %>% 
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    user session action ratio_session_posting
   <int>   <int> <chr>                  <dbl>
 1     1       1 v                      0.667
 2     1       1 v                      0.667
 3     1       1 v                      0.667
 4     1       2 d                      0.667
 5     1       2 p                      0.667
 6     1       2 p                      0.667
 7     1       3 p                      0.667
 8     2       1 v                      0.5  
 9     2       1 p                      0.5  
10     2       2 v                      0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although the output in this example is correct, but it is not correct overall. lets day i add another row as a duplication of the first row. The output should be still 0.667, but in your solution the output would be 1.00